# Regex: Find all tags whose words begin with capital letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this 3 cases.

```
<title>Continuity Between "kNOWING" AND 'fEELING'</title>
<title>Baby's lettter</title>
<title>Baby's Letter</title>
```

I want a regex to match only the 3 tag, because all words starts with capital letters.

Comment: This is not a regex writing service. What effort have you made to do this yourself before posting here? (I'll offer a deal, though - I want a new Tesla. I'll give you what you want if you give me what I want first. If that won't work for you, then do exactly what I'm doing, which is to put some work into getting it yourself.)

Comment: @JustMe While that's possible, you won't get high-quality answers unless you provide a high-quality question.

Comment: yes, I know. this is another scenario for my last post, which maybe someone else in the world will need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A regex matching lines that contain only capitalized words could look like this:

```
<title>["' \t]?([A-Z][^ \t<]*[" '\t]*?)*<\/title>
```